# Disambiguate [theft] and [security]

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag guidance for [security](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) specifically cites theft-prevention. Should [theft](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theft) be used only when a bicycle has actually been stolen? Or some other case? If so, we should add tag guidance (currently blank) to that effect.

If they're used interchangeably, they should be merged. Though for this one, I think there's a good case to be made that both tags are fine, but need usage guidance.